# How correctly configure transaction manager in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im trying to save the data into PostgreSQL database, I configure my dataSource bean:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="123"/>
<!--        <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>-->
<!--        <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>-->
</bean>
```

then insert them into sessionFactory

```html
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.nazik.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

and configure transactionManager

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

but when I start transaction using code:

```
    @Override
public void createPerson(final Person person) {
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
       public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus){
           try{
               createPerson(person);
           }catch (RuntimeException e){
               transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
               throw e;
           }
           return null;
       }
    });
}
```

i have got an error:

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'transactionManager' is expected to be of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.adaptBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1160)
```

please explain me what am I doing wrong

Comment: Do not longer use the old xml style configuration. Use the java based version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure since I have no way to test but at least the exception says that the configuration of 'transaction manager' receives the wrong type of parameter.

you can test this way.

```
<bean id = "transactionManager"
           class = "org.hibernate.SessionFactory">
         <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

You can try to see if it is that, I leave you as an answer since I can not comment yet.

Pdt: as a personal recommendation I suggest you use JPA since it has a simpler handling of transactions

Answer (score 0):

I could test this on similar setup and configuration except I am using HibernateTemplate. Since you are using Hibernate - you should be generally using [HibernateTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTemplate.html) or even better JPA APIs ( which can be used as Hibernate underlying JPA implementation)

You can also use `@Transactional` annotation rather than programatically defining your boundaries and exception handling.

My sample configuration looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 ">
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="springmvc"></context:component-scan>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        name="viewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        name="ds">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springjdbc" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        name="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>springmvc.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate"
        name="hibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
        name="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

And my data saving code looks like this

```
@Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    
    
    @Transactional
    public int saveUser(User user) {
        int id = (Integer)this.hibernateTemplate.save(user);
        return id;
    }
```

And I can save data in database ( MySQL in my case but that is irrelevant here)

[image]